# AngularJs - $filter('filter') service does not work properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

i have a problem with the `$filter` service in Angularjs, for exemple i have an object, and i want to serach inside that object for this :  `{date: "2014-06-01",LandingPage: "/alimentation-bio-c585"}`, but the problem is that if i do `LandingPage: "/a"` it matchs and me i want it to search for the exact value not `Like %`.

My object:

```
var tab = [{"id": 1,"date": "2014-06-01","LandingPage": "/","Sales": 78},{"id": 1,"date":"2014-06-02","LandingPage": "/alimentation-bio-c585","Sales": 97}];
```

my filter:

```
var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(tab, {date: "2014-06-02",LandingPage: "a"})
```

It finds the object and i dont want it to find exept if its : `"LandingPage": "/alimentation-bio-c585"`

i saw the documentation and i added true for the comparator argument for strict mode but it didn't worked, so help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/vayuz/1/edit?html,js,output

add 'true' as third parameter to make strict  comparison

```
$scope.strictmyRedObjects = $filter('filter')
(tab, {date: "2014-06-02",LandingPage: "a"}, true);
```